# NHibernate CreateSqlQuery and addEntity

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, hibernate

The hibernate manual says this:

> String sql = "SELECT ID as {c.id}, NAME as {c.name}, " +
>
> ```
>    "BIRTHDATE as {c.birthDate}, MOTHER_ID as {c.mother}, {mother.*} " +
>
>   "FROM CAT_LOG c, CAT_LOG m WHERE {c.mother} = c.ID";
> ```
>
> List loggedCats = sess.createSQLQuery(sql)
>
> ```
>   .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
>
>   .addEntity("mother", Cat.class).list()
> ```

Now, what I have is basically the same. I am return two of the same type per row. I am doing a select something like this:

```
SELECT {ctrl1.*}, {ctrl2.*} FROM tableA AS A
                                                LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl1 ON (A.controlID = ctrl1.controlID AND ctrl1.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl1.controlOptionValue = ?)
                                                LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl2 ON (A.controlID = ctrl2.controlID AND ctrl2.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl2.controlOptionValue = ?)
```

And then I `addEntity("ctrl1", typeof(mycontrolclass)` and 
`addEntity("ctrl1", typeof(mycontrolclass)`

Which seems exactly the same to me as their example. But I get this exception:
"Could not execute query" and the inner exception is "Could not find specified column in results".
If I copy the sql in the exception(to which it has added "AS ctrl1_1_3_3_" etc) it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? I believe you might not need using either of them.

```
// Using HQL:
var motherId = 25;
var hql = "select c.birthDate, c.mother from Cat c where c.mother.Id = :motherId";
var result = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
                    .SetParameter("motherId", motherId)
                    .ToList();

// Using NHibernate.LINQ:
var result = (from cat in Session.Linq<Cat>()
             where cat.Mother.Id == motherId
             select new { cat.birthDate, cat.mother }).ToList();
```

- [**HQL query examples**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).
- [**LINQ for NHibernate examples**](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/).

Comment: Well, regardless of how the query is made up it still returns an object array. And if I have a join which joins the same table on twice it just repeats the table instead of giving the second instance for that row.

Comment: Can you explain further? I don't quite follow.

Comment: Ok lets say I do that SELECT it will return two tableB results in each row. So saying .List will return an array like:
pos 0: [tableB][tableB]
pos 1: [tableB][tableB]
But the first(in each row) tableB result(id and such) should be different to the second tableB result. But its not. Its just a repeat

Comment: I believe the OP is using CreateSQLQuery. Your answer does not address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with your problem just for studying purposes, because you will surely
have found a solution in the meanwhile, but the problem should not lie in 
the query (which is ok), but in some mapping inconsistency or somewhere else
(perhaps Database).